# javascript : stop http request when click submit

Tags: javascript

now i have a form with the validation but when i click submit it shows error but it sends request to server.

```
if(test == true) 
    .......;
else{
            if(!adviceBlock){
                el.insert({after:'<div class="validation-advice">The price should be equal or greater than <?php echo $minPrice; ?>.</div>'});

                el.addClassName('validation-failed');
            }
```

how can i stop the request when the submit button is clicked ?

Comment: Can you post the full code that catches the event and validates?

Comment: have you tried adding `return false;` on the `OnSubmit` handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent the event you are listening to:

```
event.preventDefault()
```

or, equally, return false from your function

```
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery works well here.

try this:

```
$('.myButton').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
});
```